# How to ignore a folder from navigation in expo-router?

Tags: expo, router, expo-router

Simple and maybe dumb question, but I don't see anywhere in the doc where can I completely ignore a folder from navigation.

I have for example a `src/service` folder, where there are no 'pages' nor nothing UI related, so I want to completely **igonore** it

What is the right way to handle this scenario ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Which version of expo-router are you using? If you are using version 2.0 then expo-router would look for pages only in `/app` or the `/src/app` directories and the `src/service` folder is automatically ignored. See [here](https://blog.expo.dev/introducing-expo-router-v2-3850fd5c3ca1).

If using version 1, then expo-router would only be looking at the `/app` directory for the pages.

Comment: Thanks, this was not so obvious looking at the doc!